# Submitting an HTML table row to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need help figuring out how to submit data from a table row into PHP to be processed. I would need it to be able to submit multiple rows of data. Any ideas?

I have a table [here](http://jsfiddle.net/djp122/cp6ne/). I want to be able to check the row and submit the data to php to process the data. It is an HTML table. I just want to know how to pass the variables to php, e.g. an array or something

Ok guys something like this:

```
$("submit_btn").click(function () {

       $('#diary tbody>tr input:checked').each(function() {
           $.post('process.php', 
                data: "an array",
                success: "data submitted");
       }

});
```

How would I get the table row data in an array to submit it? (Answer is below)

Ok Part 2:

Sending the table row data to php.

jQuery code:

```
    rows = JSON.stringify(rows); // submit this using $.post(...)
    alert(rows);
    $.post('classes/process.php', rows, function(data) {
      $('#results').html(data);
    })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    });
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$rowsArray = json_decode($_POST['rows']);

echo $rowsArray;
?>
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: rows in C:\...\classes\process.php on line 6
```

Comment: "Any ideas?" Yes. Show your attempt.

Comment: I don't have an attempt. I am sitting here trying to figure out where to start. If I had any ideas I would have been working on it. Don't mean to be mean, just letting you know. Thanks for the help though.<br /> -- edit here is what I have to start [link](http://jsfiddle.net/djp122/cp6ne/)

Comment: Define "a table row."  An HTML table?  At its simplest, your HTML would have a form or some collection of form elements for data input.  You'd send those values to the server in a POST.  It really sounds like you're just looking for a starter tutorial.  Have you found one that you're trying to follow but not understanding?

Comment: It's too vague of a question for us to answer.

Comment: Can you please post your code that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the replies though. I am trying to be as clear as possible. I have linked a table that I am using as my starting grounds. I haven't even started on this problem just thought I would ask since I don't know where to start. Thanks again for at least trying to help.

Comment: It's a fair question. I don't understand the negatives. He wants to send a table row in array form to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(){
    var rows = [];
    $('#box-table-a tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(i,v){
        var tds = $(v).parents('tr').children('td');
        rows.push({
            'name': tds.eq(1).find('select').val(),
            'units': tds.eq(2).text(),
            'calories': tds.eq(3).text(),
            'sugar': tds.eq(4).text()
        });
    });
    rows = JSON.stringify(rows); // submit this using $.post(...)
    $.post('classes/process.php', {'rows': rows}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

submit `rows` using a $.post() and then, in the server side, you can convert back into an array using `json_decode()`;

**Sample output:**

[{"name":"Water","units":"1","calories":"2","sugar":"3"},{"name":"Food","units":"4","calories":"5","sugar":"6"}]

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/cp6ne/84/

Comment: Thanks for the help. That is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for not being real clear. I did not know where to start and was unsure of how to ask. But thanks for yours and everyone elses help.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind I am getting an error with php. my php is <?php $rowsArray = json_decode($_POST['rows']; echo $rowArray; ?> It gives me this error: Unidentified index: rows on line 3. Any sugguestions?

Comment: how are you sending the `$.post();` ?

Comment: your `$.post()` is wrong. Look at my updated answer. Send `rows` as an object: `{'rows': rows}`, this way, in php you can access `$_POST['rows'];`

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know that I am still very new to ajax and json. Thanks again for you help.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the jQuery library to make an AJAX request to a PHP script that then 'processed' the data in the table.

You could also use the jQuery .each() function to perform this action on multiple rows.