# Retrieve a specific row value from table HTML and submit it to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm populating a table from my database and it looks like this :

```
<form name = "Form" role="form" action ="php/teilnehmen.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
                        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Studienfach</th>
                                    <th>Teilnehmer/in</th>
                                    <th>Teilnehmen</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
//<?php php code..... 
$i =0;
$sizeofstudienfaecherseperate = 
count($studienfaecherseperate);
for ($i; $i < $sizeofstudienfaecherseperate; $i++) {

?>
                                        <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td ><?php echo($i+1);?></td>
        <td class="studienfach"><?php echo($studienfaecherseperate[$i]);?>
 <input   type="hidden" name="PARAM_STUDIENFACH" id="PARAM_STUDIENFACH" 
 value="<?php echo($studienfaecherseperate[$i]);?>"> </input>
        </td>
                                    <td ><?php echo($teilnehmer[$i]);?></td>
                                    <td width="10%">
         <?php if ($teilnahmestatus[$i] =="0"){ ?>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success use-address" 
 name="teilnehmern"id="teilnehmen">Teilnehmen</button>
 <?php }else{?>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger use-address" name="teilnahme-beenden" 
 id="teilnahme-beenden">Teilnahme beenden</button>
 <?php }?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
      </fieldset>                  <!-- /.table-responsive -->
```

the table  is shown great, and my problem is when i try to submit my second column value **"PARAM_STUDIENFACH"** of a specific row to my php webservice. It always gives me back the last value. I know that because I'm using the same **id** in every row so it will be overwritten. I tried using JavaScript to return the value of the clicked row from other questions in the forum but it didn't work for me. I'm using a bootstrap table if that helps.

**EDIT 1 :**

Thanks to @Taplar answer I managed to find a solution to my problem. I used this JavaScript to retrieve the data and ajax to send a post request. This is the code I used :

```
$(".use-address").click(function() {

var item = $(this).closest("tr")   // Finds the closest row <tr> 
                   .find(".studienfach")     // Gets a descendent with class="nr"
                   .text();         // Retrieves the text within <td>
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "php/teilnehmen.php",
        data: {PARAM_STUDIENFACH:item},
        success: function(data){
            alert(item);
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(e.message);
        }
});

});
```

my problem now is in the alert the "item" shows correctly but in my database it is saved as the following example :

item = a (shows in alert a)

item = a \n (it's saved like that in the database with spaces afeter \n)

i tried to trim the item before sending it but i got the same result

to get the item sent by ajax i'm using this line of code in :

```
$studienfach = null;

if(isset($_POST['PARAM_STUDIENFACH']))
    $studienfach = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['PARAM_STUDIENFACH']);
```

**EDIT 2:**

i managed to solve my second problem by doing this :

```
$pos= strpos($studienfach, "\\");
$studienfachtemp = substr($studienfach, 0,$pos);
trim($studienfachtemp);
```

if there is more elegent or correct way to do it ! please post it ! thank you all.

Comment: There's zero database code here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: Why didn't javascript work for you?

Comment: It's a duplicate id issue instead of using classes and doing a contextual find. @MarcodeZeeuw

Comment: @MarcodeZeeuw honestly i don't know ! this is the link i tried : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910529/submitting-an-html-table-row-to-php)

Comment: @Taplar i'm aware that the id must be unique ! but i don't know how to avoid that problem ! any suggestions ? i'm new in this field.. how to use calsses and do a contextual search ?

Comment: You don't know how to not duplicate ids?

Comment: @tadman the database code is too long and i don't see that it's relevant in this problem.. because the table is displayed correctly as i want it ! my problem is only when i try to retrieve data from a specific row and send it to php

Comment: @Taplar i'm populating the table with a for loop ! if i give the id a different value everytime a row is populated for example : id values = 1,2,3,4,5 ! and 
 when i click on the button in the second row.. how i'm supposed to know that that's the row that was clicked and returns the value of the id=2 ?

Comment: See my answer below please.  You don't use ids for this.  You use classes.  Classes are valid to be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<elem1>
    <elem2 class="getMe"></elem2>
    <elem3></elem3>
</elem1>
```

Quick contextual lookup reference.  Say you have a click event bound on all 'elem3' on your page.  When you click it you want to get the associated 'elem2', not all of them.  With the class you can contextually look this element up by doing...

```
//'this' being the elem3 that was clicked
$(this).closest('elem1').find('.getMe');
```

From the element you clicked, it will find the shared 'elem1' parent of both 'elem2' and 'elem3' and then find only the '.getMe' that belongs to that parent.

More reading material: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/

Comment: I managed to find a solution by using your answer ! please check my edited question because i have an other little problem left ! thank you in advance

Comment: Instead of altering your question, you might consider making a new one.  It's hard to provide answers to questions that are changing.  @user3816569